# How to handle pipe and bind variable in execute immediate

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have something like this :

```
declare

begin

dbms_output.put_line('some text'|| :bind_variable||'again some text');

end;
```

I want to run the begin block dynamically but not able to do it by execute immediate .

The below code prompts for bind_variable:

```
declare
begin
execute immediate '
dbms_output.put_line(''some text''|| ':bind_variable'||''again some text'');
'
;
end;
```

But throws the below error:

```
Error starting at line : 3 in command -
declare

begin

execute immediate '
dbms_output.put_line(''some text''|| ':bind_variable'||''again some text'');
'
;
end;

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 39:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return
   returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or
   like like2 like4 likec between into using || multiset bulk
   member submultiset
The symbol "* was inserted before "" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I am not sure how to put the begin block  in `execute immediate` .

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You don't need bind variable, you can run

```
bind_variable := ' some variable text';
dbms_output.put_line('some text'|| bind_variable||'again some text');
```

If you really need dynamic statement you can use

```
execute immediate 
   'dbms_output.put_line(''some text :bind_variable again some text'')'  
   USING bind_variable;
```

However, I am not sure whether you can use bind variables in `dbms_output.put_line` - but I assume you got the principle.

Comment: Hi Wernfried,begin


   dbms_output.put_line('some text'|| :bind_variable|| 'again some text');
  
   
   end;
If this works , then bind_variable in execute immediate should also work

Comment: What is your real code? For sure `dbms_output.put_line('some text'|| :bind_variable|| 'again some text');` will not work.

Comment: Did you  try running the code ?It is working for me in anonymous block ,just that I want to put it in execute immediate.

Comment: I don't understand. Again, please show us your real code then we can tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. use `VARIABLE` command . It works in SQL*Plus and in SQL developer and Toad when executed as script.

```
VARIABLE bind_variable VARCHAR2(20)

EXEC :bind_variable := ' TEXT IN BETWEEN '

set serveroutput on
declare
begin

 dbms_output.put_line('some text'|| :bind_variable||'again some text');

end;
/

some text TEXT IN BETWEEN again some text


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If you want to prompt for user input, use substitution variables using `&`.

```
dbms_output.put_line('some text &sub_variable again some text');
```